# Сумма минимального и максимального элементов массива

Tags: массивы, c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[100], max, min, n;
    cin >> n;
    max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (min > a[i]) {
            min = a[i];
        }
        if (max < a[i]) {
            max = a[i];
        }
    }
    cout << max + min;
    return 0;
}
```

Данный алгоритм выводит не верное значение. Причину найти не могу. Пробовал находить отдельно минимальное и максимальное. Находит лишь минимальное, а в максимальном получаю ошибку.

Comment: А чему до циклов равны `min` и `max`? Инициализируйте, и будет Вам щастье

Comment: Исправил, выводит предпоследний елемент... можно пример кода?

Comment: и чего вы исправили? где инициализация min?

Comment: добавьте min = INT_MAX; max = INT_MIN;

Comment: Всем спасибо, разобрался)

Comment: @alexlz, ну да, тупанул :) Самого элементарного и простого решения не заметил...

Comment: @zok1995, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 3):

[@MDJHD](/users/16739/mdjhd) Хм. Ну ладно, тут int == long, но это не везде. А вставить константу, затем поменять тип переменно -- и глюк готов. Лучше `min = max = a[0];`. Да и имена min и max лучше не трогать. Спокойнее.

Comment: @alexlz согласен, что min = max = a[0]; лучше. Но поясните, пожалуйста, причем тут long ?

Comment: @nanotexnik на платформе, где long и int отличаются, описываем  

     int min, max;
     min = INT_MIN;
     max = INT_MAX;

Затем нам потребовалось заменить int на long (разрядов не хватает). А инициализацию забыли поменять. Возникает ошибка, которая может проявляться очень редко -- чаще оно будет работать правильно. А когда придёт глюк, у автора может случиться куча удивления.

Comment: Значит надо просто написать платформонезависимые макросы (или функции, если макросы не нравятся), которые возвращают MIN и MAX для заданной переменной.

Comment: @avp Не-а. Проще надо писать, чтобы таких мест было поменьше.

Comment: @alexlz, золотые слова (KISS-принцип). 


Особенно, когда как в случае

     xmin = xmax = a[0];

это еще и достаточно общее решение.

--

А по поводу обобщенных `I_MIN(var)` и `I_MAX(var)` -- это я просто для желающих развлечься "разминку для хвоста" подкинул.

Comment: @avp: для C++ подойдёт `numeric_limits<decltype(xmin)>::max()` и т. п. А как в чистом C, чтобы работало со всеми типами?

Comment: @VladD, думаю, так подойдет


    #ifdef CHAR_BIT
    #define _CB CHAR_BIT
    #else
    #define _CB 8
    #endif
    
    #define I_MIN(v) ({long long l = -1; l  <<= (sizeof(typeof(v)) * _CB - 1); l;})
    #define I_MAX(v) ({long long l = I_MIN(v); ~l;})
    ....
      char mic = I_MIN(mic); short smax = I_MAX(smax); 
      int imin = I_MIN(imin); long lmax = I_MAX(lmax); 
    
      printf ("%d %d %d %ld\n", mic, smax, imin, lmax);

по крайней мере в одной системе работает

    -128 32767 -2147483648 9223372036854775807

Comment: @avp нет, Вы точно садист.

Comment: @alexlz, а в чем проблема?

Один раз пишется, инклюдом подключаеся...

Единственно, надо помнить (при передаче в printf и т.п.), что на самом деле результат этих макро -- `long long`.

А может, лучше привести результат к типу параметра макры?

    #define I_MAX(v) ({long long l = I_MIN(v); (typeof(v))(~l);})

и аналогично для `I_MIN`.

Comment: @avp: о, классно, битовые трюки. Только зачем нестандартное `{}`-выражение? Можно ведь по идее написать эквивалентно

    #define I_MIN(v) (-1LL << (sizeof(typeof(v)) * _CB - 1))

---
А в динамическом по идее нужен `unsigned char`, так как signed-переполнение есть UB. (зануда mode off)